# como actualizo datos en django

Tags: django

Estoy aprendiendo Django y tengo un modelo Pelicula y un modelo Usuario y lo que quiero hacer es, en la vista me muestra todas las pelis y tengo una opcion en cada peli q es agregar a favoritos, lo q quiero logra es eso como hago eso dejo mi codigo

Esta bien q lo haga con un formulario y en la views use el UpdateView, pero como obtengo el dato en la vista y el usuario logueado?

El usuario inicia sesión y lo manda a la vista donde están la lista de pelis con las opciones de editar,eliminar,ver y agregar Favorito , que todas esas funcionan menos la ultima q no logro como pensarlo.

mi modelo

```
class Pelicula(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sinopsis = models.TextField()
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genero = models.ManyToManyField(Genero)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Usuario(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favoritos = models.ManyToManyField(Pelicula)
    bloqueado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username

@receiver(post_save, sender= User)
def crear_usuario(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = Usuario(usuario=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(crear_usuario, sender=User)
```

la vista

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView,UpdateView,ListView,DeleteView,DetailView
from .models import Pelicula, Usuario, Genero
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import PeliculaForm, UsuarioForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin

class PeliculaListView(PermissionRequiredMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Pelicula
    permission_required = 'peliculas.view_pelicula'
    template_name = "pelicula/pelicula_lista.html"
class PeliculaCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Pelicula
    form_class = PeliculaForm
    permission_required = 'peliculas.add_pelicula'
    template_name = "pelicula/pelicula_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pelicula:lista')

class PeliculaListView(PermissionRequiredMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Pelicula
    permission_required = 'peliculas.view_pelicula'
    template_name = "pelicula/pelicula_lista.html"
    
class PeliculaDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Pelicula
    permission_required = 'peliculas.view_pelicula'
    template_name = "pelicula/pelicula_detalle.html"
     
class PeliculaDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Pelicula
    form_class = PeliculaForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pelicula:lista')
    permission_required = 'peliculas.delete_pelicula'
```

el template

```
<table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Direccion</th>
            <th>Generos</th>
            <th>Sinopsis</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            {% for peli in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ peli.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ peli.direccion }}</td>  
                <td>        
            {% for p in peli.genero.all %}
                {{ p.nombre }}
            {% endfor %}
            </td>
                <td>{{ peli.sinopsis }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% if perms.peliculas.view_pelicula %}
                        <a class="btn" href="{% url 'pelicula:detalle' peli.pk %}">Detalle</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if perms.peliculas.change_pelicula %}  
                        <a class="btn" href="{% url 'pelicula:editar' peli.pk %}">Editar</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if perms.peliculas.delete_pelicula %}
                        <form action="{% url 'pelicula:eliminar' peli.pk %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Eliminar</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form action="{% url 'pelicula:add_favorito' peli.pk %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Favorito</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
</table>
```